# weird issue when downloading from the app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, app-store

I am getting the following error after doing an upgrade from the app store. I tried simulating this in Xcode by installing the previous version and then running the new update via XCode and I didn't get this error. What is going on? Is this one of those apple app store DRM issues?

```
 <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: No IMEI in CT mobile equipment info dictionary - <CFBasicHash 0xee6c450 [0x3f004650]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
    entries =>
        2 : <CFString 0xee6c400 [0x3f004650]>{contents = "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoMEID"} = <CFString 0xee6c430 [0x3f004650]>{contents = "A100001CB0E219"}
        3 : <CFString 0xee6c500 [0x3f004650]>{contents = "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoMIN"} = <CFString 0xee6bcd0 [0x3f004650]>{contents = "5204299292"}
        7 : <CFString 0xee6bd10 [0x3f004650]>{contents = "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoPRLVersion"} = <CFNumber 0xee68de0 [0x3f004650]>{value = +52333, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    }
Jul  6 14:38:31 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 01633000 copy_imei: MobileGestalt failed to provide an IMEI
Jul  6 14:38:31 unknown lockdownd[26] <Notice>: 01633000 copy_iccid: invalid ICCID from CT/no ICCID available
Jul  6 14:38:31 unknown wifid[13] <Error>: WiFi:[363303511.631083]: Client itunesstored is background application
Jul  6 14:38:31 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: TRACE: <MBConnection: 0x145210> sending {
        command = kMBMessageAccountChanged;
    }
Jul  6 14:38:31 unknown configd[45] <Notice>: network configuration changed.
>
```

Comment: ...it would help if you actually posted the error you were seeing.

Comment: sorry.. I forgot to attach the error. but it's there now

Answer (score 2):

It could be, but Apple has stated they have resolved the problem. You can check [this post](http://www.marco.org/2012/07/04/app-store-corrupt-binaries).

Comment: Yea.. that's why I am worried about. If they already fixed it then why am I getting this error?